# Python Grade Book Assignment, writing and reading records, and totals of letter grades, cannot get correct output

Tags: python

This is the problem: Create a Python program that allows user enter class name, faculty name, name of each student, and letter grade each student earned. The program should count and display numbers of students who earned As, Bs, Cs, Ds, and Fs. And the program should save all input and output information into a text file named ClassNameGrades.txt.

The code I have written so far is below. I am just learning and this is very rudimentary, I apologize. Below that is the output. I don't know why I am getting 2 extra records to pop up. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? The file is created, the input is written into the file, but then it falls apart during the read.

```
def main():


    student_num = 0
    count = 0
    a_total = 0
    b_total = 0
    c_total = 0
    d_total = 0
    f_total = 0
    student_num = int(input("Enter the number of students you wish to enter 
    grades for: "))
    gradefile = open('gradebook.txt', 'w')
    for count in range(1, student_num + 1):
        class_name = input('Enter class name: ')
        faculty_name = input('Enter faculty name: ')
        student_name = input('Enter student name: ')
        letter_grade = input('Enter letter grade (A, B, C, D, or F) ')
        print()
        if letter_grade.upper() == 'A':
            a_total += 1
        elif letter_grade.upper() == 'B':
            b_total += 1
        elif letter_grade.upper() == 'C':
            c_total += 1
        elif letter_grade.upper() == 'D':
            d_total += 1
        elif letter_grade.upper() == 'F':
            f_total += 1
        else:
            print('Invalid response')
        gradefile.write(class_name + '\n')
        gradefile.write(faculty_name + '\n')
        gradefile.write(student_name + '\n')
        gradefile.write(letter_grade + '\n')

    gradefile.write(str(a_total) + '\n')
    gradefile.write(str(b_total) + '\n')
    gradefile.write(str(c_total) + '\n')
    gradefile.write(str(d_total) + '\n')
    gradefile.write(str(f_total) + '\n')
    gradefile.close()

    gradefile1 = open('gradebook.txt', 'r')

    class_name = gradefile1.readline()
    while class_name != '':
        faculty_name = gradefile1.readline()
        student_name = gradefile1.readline()
        letter_grade = gradefile1.readline()

        class_name = class_name.rstrip('\n')
        faculty_name = faculty_name.rstrip('\n')
        student_name = student_name.rstrip('\n')
        letter_grade = letter_grade.rstrip('\n')

        print('Class name: ', class_name)
        print('Faculty name: ', faculty_name)
        print('Student name: ', student_name)
        print('Letter grade: ', letter_grade.upper())
        print()
        class_name = gradefile1.readline()
    a_total = gradefile1.readline()
    b_total = gradefile1.readline()
    c_total = gradefile1.readline()
    d_total = gradefile1.readline()
    f_total = gradefile1.readline()
    a_total = a_total.rstrip('\n')
    b_total = b_total.rstrip('\n')
    c_total = c_total.rstrip('\n')
    d_total = d_total.rstrip('\n')
    f_total = f_total.rstrip('\n')
    print('Total As: ', a_total)
    print('Total Bs: ', b_total)
    print('Total Cs: ', c_total)
    print('Total Ds: ', d_total)
    print('Total Fs: ', f_total)
    gradefile1.close()
main()
```

User Input:

```
Enter the number of students you wish to enter grades for: 3
Enter class name: bio
Enter faculty name: jones
Enter student name: smith
Enter letter grade (A, B, C, D, or F) A

Enter class name: bio
Enter faculty name: jones
Enter student name: gray
Enter letter grade (A, B, C, D, or F) B

Enter class name: Bio
Enter faculty name: Jones
Enter student name: Thomas
Enter letter grade (A, B, C, D, or F) B
```

Returned output:

```
Class name:  bio
Faculty name:  jones
Student name:  smith
Letter grade:  A

Class name:  bio
Faculty name:  jones
Student name:  gray
Letter grade:  B

Class name:  Bio
Faculty name:  Jones
Student name:  Thomas
Letter grade:  B

Class name:  1
Faculty name:  2
Student name:  0
Letter grade:  0

Class name:  0
Faculty name:  
Student name:  
Letter grade:  

Total As:  
Total Bs:  
Total Cs:  
Total Ds:  
Total Fs:  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are reading the file you spect to find a blank line between students data and totals data but you have not written one.
So `while class_name != ''` isn't false until you've reed the whole file.

Add a blank line between and your code will work.

```
[...]
gradefile.write('\n')
gradefile.write(str(a_total) + '\n')
```

Comment: I thought that would work, too. I tried it, but it just shifts the output down one line so the first extra class name is blank but then it enters the letter grade totals like the original output. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I got it to work by putting in while class_name != ('\n')

Answer (score 0):

While im not with my developer at the moment, having a breif look at your code,  I beleive the issue is with the for statement. Instead of range(1, student_num+1) try to rewrite it so you instead use student_num input value as the amount of iterations. Based one the way you have it written I beleive what is happening is the for loop is counting the iterations incorrectly because of student_num+1. If the user enters 3 for student_num then 3 should be the only amount of iterations specified.